# .htaccess redirect subdomain to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am developing a website in which user registers with some of their personal data. Each of them get a unique URL to their profile (Please see the below example). 
Is there any way to get a unique url like a subdomain to each users with htaccess rewrite rule ?

> Example

```
 For John - john.example.com > example.com/user.php?username=john
 For Emma - emma.example.com > example.com/user.php?username=emma
```

I have some other redirect rules for other pages like ***login, registration*** etc
Is there any way ?

Live example - https://john.sarahah.com, https://emma.sarahah.com

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules use regular expressions, so you have full power:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap    lowercase int:tolower

RewriteCond   "${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}}"   "^([^.]+)\.example\.com$"
RewriteRule   "^(.*)" "https://example.com/user.php?username=%1;path=$1" [R,L]
```

This is almost the first example at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/vhosts.html